# React native fetch local images causes error "RangeError Failed to construct 'Response': The status provided (0) is outside the range [200, 599]"

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, expo, expo-camera

Here is the function that uses expo-camera to take a picture, and this works correctly

```
//Local Image State object, for file URL, Firebase URL
  const [image, setImage] = useState([]);
  const [fireURI, setURI] = useState([]); 

 const takePicture = async () => {

    // null parameter, options are set on Camera component not in takePicAsync()
    const data = await camera.takePictureAsync(null);
    const source = await data.uri;

    setImage([...image, source]);
    //Renders photo after
    setUploading(true);
    //Closes camera
    setIsCameraOpen(false);
    setZoom(0);

  };
```

And here is the function that send the images to Firebase storage and gets the download URL for each, this was working before and now all of a sudden I get error **"RangeError Failed to construct 'Response': The status provided (0) is outside the range [200, 599]"**

```
  const handleFirebaseURI = async () => {
    const ImageURL = [];
    image.map(async (images) => {
      var metadata = {
        contentType: "image/jpeg",
      };
      // ERROR HERE ON FETCH, if I remove the firebase logic the error still occurs
      const response = await fetch(images);
      const blob = await response.blob();
      const filename = await images.substring(images.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
      //Reference to Firebase storage, folder created for each user email
      const imageRef = ref(storage, `${ID}/${filename}`);
      try {
        //Uploads Image to Firebase Storage
        const uploadTask = await uploadBytes(imageRef, blob, metadata);
        // Get the download URL and wait for its resolution
        const url = await getDownloadURL(uploadTask.ref);
        ImageURL.push(url);
        setImages({ ImageURL });
        setUploadingToFirebase(true);
      } catch (error) {
        alert(error);
      }
    });
```

What is causing the error when fetching local files?
All of this code was working fine recently what could have changed?